# pandas fillna specific columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Below is an example of my DF

```
col1      col2     col3    col4 
Comp1     False    01St    97
Comp2     False    02St    97
Comp3     True     03St    97
Comp4     False    04St    97
```

The Aim would be to fillna col3 & col4 when col2 == True

Below is what I've tried so far

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()[-2]
df[cols] = np.where(df.col2 == True, np.nan, df[cols])
```

The expected ouput

```
col1      col2     col3    col4 
Comp1     False    01St    97
Comp2     False    02St    97
Comp3     True     NaN     NaN
Comp4     False    04St    97
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
# two last columns
cols = df.columns[-2:]
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df['col2'])
```

or assignment with `iloc`:

```
# 2 not 3
df.iloc[df['col2'], 2:] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
    col1   col2  col3  col4
0  Comp1  False  01St  97.0
1  Comp2  False  02St  97.0
2  Comp3   True   NaN   NaN
3  Comp4  False  04St  97.0
```